# export a class instance from c++ cli to c#

Tags: c++-cli

When exporting my C++ code to C# using C++/CLI, I want to create an instance of a specific class in C++/CLI, in order to use it from various C# classes

For example
in C++/CLI

```
namespace Example
{
    public ref class Foo
    {
        Foo(int i) {...}
    };
}
```

In C# I want to use instance of `Foo` like `Example.Foo1` (as Foo1=Foo(1))

I tried

```
namespace Example
{
    public ref class Foo
    {
        Foo(int i) {...}
    };
    gcroot<Foo^> Foo1 = gcnew Foo(1);
}
```

But it doesn't work. Can anybody suggest a solution?

Comment: It is not very clear why you wrote a Foo() constructor with an argument when you *really* need a public static property that exposes the object.  Or better yet, that C# code should have a static variable since it is the code that seems to care about having one object.

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't support global variables. (Neither does C++/CLI, actually: It turns them into a static variable on a hidden class behind the scenes.)

C# doesn't support gcroot.

Just declare a static variable on your class and fill it.

```
namespace Example
{
    public ref class Foo
    {
    public:
        Foo(int i) {...}

        static Foo^ Foo1 = gcnew Foo(1);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. But in C# I have to call like Example.Foo.Foo1